# Hot to center those 3 divs into the body

Tags: html, css

Im wondering how to center those 3 divs into he body, i created 2 versions of the row, one with an extra outer wrap around the column and one without, Unfortuinatly since this html created with a page builder (WP visual composer) so i dont have 100% freedom to control the html structure. I tried margin: auto but couldn't make it to work.

You can find the divs im talking about on this page.
https://bonmedico.de/test/

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Please create a [mcve] within your question using the edit link and the snippet button on the wysiwyg

Comment: @Paulie_D I think if you had a look into the html code and its connected css outputed from the page builder you will see why i couldnt post it on the question.

Comment: you can ' replicate ' the problem posed by visual composer which essentially just uses flex box with some ' fancy ' classes.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This question will be closed very soon because it's not according to SO rules. ( Read comments to your question to find about that ). You really should put more effort when writing questions.

But i took a look at your website. You can solve your problem in 2 ( maybe more ) ways.

1. add `justify-content:center` to the parent row of those 3 columns. Being a `display: flex` element it will center them horizontally.
2. using visual composer is easy. Just add 2 small columns ( empty ) left and right and a larger column in the middle. Something like 1/4 1/2 1/4. And in that ' bigger ' column you can add a new row continaing 3 columns ( like you have now ).  Or there are more possibilities to do this. Just ' play ' around with visual composer

Comment: Thanks so much for your help and i apologize for the way i posted the question, i just couldnt think of a good way to post the Visual Composer code in the question and though it might be more clear to post the website link itself

Comment: glad i could help. Here on SO links to external sites are not allowed. Just try to replicate your problem with a code snippet. Tht being said, i don't know why the answer got so many downvotes as it solves the problem. Maybe the downvoters don't want to encourage answers to these types of questions :)